# Screenshots using headless google-chrome come out blank

Tags: google-chrome, debian

I did this on an AWS lightsail debian instance. I followed the instructions on https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-google-chrome-web-browser-on-debian-9/ and was able to install chrome successfully. But, when taking screenshots they all come out blank.

This is the command I used: `google-chrome --headless --disable-gpu --screenshot myfile.html`

Specifying the screen size didn't do anything.